# Why does putting two data sets with a Time Cartesian axis in Chart.js cause two Y axis tick sets?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('chart');

function genMockData() {
  return {
    x: moment().add(moment.duration(Math.random() * 10, 'hours')).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
    y: Math.random() * 100
  }
}

new Chart(canvas, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      data: [genMockData(), genMockData(), genMockData()]
    }, {
      data: [genMockData(), genMockData(), genMockData()]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'time'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

While it seems that both datasets are scaled based on the same Y axis, adding 'time' as a type settings for the x axis causes two sets of ticks (one being 0-1, in decimal intervals) on the Y axis. How do I get rid of the 0-1 ticks on the Y axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in your config you specify a new axis and since you dont specify a placement it makes it a y axis, removing the `axis` part will solve your issue

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('chart');

function genMockData() {
  return {
    x: moment().add(moment.duration(Math.random() * 10, 'hours')).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
    y: Math.random() * 100
  }
}

new Chart(canvas, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      data: [genMockData(), genMockData(), genMockData()]
    }, {
      data: [genMockData(), genMockData(), genMockData()]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
         type: 'time'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@0.1.1"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: No your problem was a second y axis, the problem also was already in your code but didn't appear because you tried placing items in a place where chart.js ignores them so it was never a time Cartesian scale

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry for the downvote then, it wont let me reverse it unless you make some edit.

Comment: Well added data adapter which you need and now it is a time axis